# How to reduce the number of requests from Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, optimization, request

Actually I have done with the Wordpress website optimization through wp-optimize, Smush and wp-fastest-cache plugins and also optimizes images.
So my website speed reduced from 20+ seconds to 12-14 seconds almost.
But, I have checked with gtmetrix.com and pingdom tool, the number of requests from our website is still as it is (i.e. about 260+) and which is so harmful for SEO perspective.
I have to reduced those number of requests from our website and also increased speed from 14 seconds to 7 seconds.
So, what type of plugins or some custom activities I need to do for reducing number of requests from our website.
Please suggest.

Comment: You could use https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/fast-velocity-minify/ to merge your css and js files. (If you make changes to your css or js you have to delete the plugins cache and recreate the minified version)

Answer (score 0):

Consider abandoning any use of plugins that perform these functions. Everything you are getting with compression plugins, is a simple job you can do yourself, lightening the processes and allowing Wordpress to be leaner and more secure.

As far as excessive requests are concerned, the same principle as stated above applies. The use of third-party plugins, involves a massive expenditure of useless resources and calls to scripts that are often redundant on all pages. The work to be done is to exclude all requests for various scripts in unnecessary pages.

Let's take a trivial example. By installing the Woocommerce plugin that everyone uses, they don't realize that the plugin in question preloads all the additional files it needs on each page and not on the pages that are strictly necessary. Like for example the js that allows the product gallery, it is also loaded into the homepage where it does not exist.

So be patient, check every additional request and exclude it if not necessary using the simple native Wordpress functions.

Forgive my bad English, but I hope I made myself understood.